# Postgresql: how to enable pg_stat_replication_slots?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a streaming replication on pg 14.2 that seems to be working, on a slot named `slot1`.

`select * from pg_stat_replication_slots` has no output. Do I need to enable anything else?

I have those on:

- track_activities
- track_counts

Streaming INFO:

`select * from pg_stat_replication;`

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+------------------------------
pid              | 21483
usesysid         | 376382
usename          | repl
application_name | replication
client_addr      | 172.28.201.16
client_hostname  | 
client_port      | 42822
backend_start    | 2022-03-17 11:25:05.599057-03
backend_xmin     | 
state            | streaming
sent_lsn         | 56/4729C750
write_lsn        | 56/4729C750
flush_lsn        | 56/4729C750
replay_lsn       | 56/46007120
write_lag        | 00:00:00.005546
flush_lag        | 00:00:00.011271
replay_lag       | 00:59:34.522039
sync_priority    | 0
sync_state       | async
reply_time       | 2022-03-17 12:24:49.02266-03
```

`select * from pg_replication_slots;`

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+------------
slot_name           | slot1
plugin              | 
slot_type           | physical
datoid              | 
database            | 
temporary           | f
active              | t
active_pid          | 21483
xmin                | 
catalog_xmin        | 
restart_lsn         | 56/47313758
confirmed_flush_lsn | 
wal_status          | reserved
safe_wal_size       | 10750970024
two_phase           | f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important word in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-REPLICATION-SLOTS-VIEW):

> The pg_stat_replication_slots view will contain one row per **logical** replication slot, showing statistics about its usage.

As intended, there is nothing for *physical* replication slots here. Perhaps this view could be called differently, but now it's too late to rename.

Comment: Thanks, I did look at the docs but missed this detail.